# Healthservice.exe iops

Tags: scom

Does anyone have information on the ideal IOPS read and writes for Healthservice.exe(SCOM/MMA). We are dealing with a situation of high IOPS from healthservice.exe and appreciate any help
Thanks,
Sai

Answer (score 0):

I think ideal is very YMMV, but if it is more than you are comfortable with, you may have too many rules or monitoring processes running. You can try restarting the service, as well as take a look at the link below for ideas.
https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/systemcenter/en-US/bd2311f7-6b9d-4157-b7fd-ae67856fe52f/healthserviceexe-100-cpu?forum=operationsmanagergeneral

Comment: Thanks Nick. We did the same and it came down but we were still looking for the ideal and other long term solutions. Thanks.